# Triangulate location with Python having 3 anchors and 1 tag

Tags: python

I have 4 sensors: 3 anchors and 1 tag. The 3 anchors measure the distance the tag is located.

Anchor 1 is 30 cm to the left of anchor 2.
Anchor 3 is 30 cm from the center between anchor 1 and anchor 2.

The diameter of the distance of anchor 1 and anchor 2 is 530 cm (distance at which the tag is located). The diameter of the distance from anchor 3 is 600 cm (distance at which the tag is located).

There is a point that collides between all the diameters of the anchor and that is the position of the person.

I want to know in code:

1. How far away is the person (straight line from the center).
2. Whether the person is in front, back, left, or right.

Honestly, I can't think of a way to do it in real life and that's why I'm asking for help, I'm a bit lost. Who can help me, please?

[image]

```
# My sensor gives me this variable data, but, let's use these default values
# Distance where the person (tag) is
anchor_1 = 530
anchor_2 = 530
anchor_3 = 600
```

I found this library, but, I don't think it can help much since it uses GPS data, my sensors are not GPS: https://github.com/ricardojoserf/triangle-position

Comment: do you know how your would work this out with a pen, paper and a calculator?  You need to work out how to solve it before you can write some code that solves it.

Comment: Sincerely I dont know. I'm here to ask for a little guide from someone who knows how to do it so I can get started.

Comment: Isn't this just finding the intersection point of 3 circles that are described by 2D points and radiuses? See e.g. http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circles3/Intersection.htm

Comment: Yes I think so. What I explained is according to my logic, I don't know the formulas.

Comment: Well, search for circle-circle intersection? :)

Comment: @principemestizo3  The clue is in 'Triangulation'. Draw some triangles on there. Write on the known lengths.  #1 is basically just Pythagoras

Comment: @principemestizo3 The library you've found should work fine, you'll just need to change the earth distance calculations to regular cartesian coordinate distances.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `530,530,600` cannot be the results of the 3 sensors, as they the 3 circles will never coincide. Changing that too `530,530,560`.
Assuming your anchors are rounded of to integers, and considering the center of anchor_1 and anchor_2 as the origin of the cartesian plane, the following code will give you the rounded off coordinates of the tag

```py
anchor_1 = 530
anchor_2 = 530
anchor_3 = 560
h_dist = 30
v_dist = 30

y = round(((anchor_1**2)-((((anchor_1**2) - (anchor_2**2) + (h_dist**2))/(2*h_dist))**2))**0.5)
x = round(((anchor_1**2) - (anchor_2**2) + (h_dist**2))/(2*h_dist))

if anchor_3 == y + v_dist:
    y = -y

x = x - h_dist//2

print(x,y)
```